# Using ASP.NET Response and Request objects in a web client class

Tags: asp.net

I currently have a webclient class that maintains session for my web application using session variables but I want to instead use cookies to maintain session.  I of course don't have access to the ASP.NET Response and Request variables in this class. Would I have to pass those objects to the webclient class?

Comment: The session, is connected with the cookie of the browser, so yes, if you need to read either the session, either the cookies you need to access to response and request that are connected to the browser and get access to the cookie, and therefore to the the session.

Comment: How are you using this `WebClient` class? I am confused as to why you are using a `WebClient` class to store session data, because the `WebClient` is designed to send and receive data from a URL.

Comment: How are u currently accessing Session?

Comment: @Karl I thin OP means his own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but in any of your custom classes inside of ASP.NET application you can access Request and Response via

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
```

Comment: Duh, I am accessing the session using HttpContext.Current, I should have realized I can use that for Request and Response too.

Comment: Hence was my question "How are u currently accessing Session" :)

Answer (score 1):

As Yuriy pointed out you could access the request/response objects directly via the HttpContext.Current namespace, this however is bad practice. Your class has a dependency on the request/response objects, these should be passed into your class via it's constructor.

e.g.

```
public class SessionExample{


    public SessionExample(System.Web.HttpRequest request, System.Web.HttpResponse response){

    }

}
```

Or if your class is meant to live for longer than the duration of a single http request you can pass them in as method paramaters

```
public class SessionExample{


    public SessionExample(){

    }

    public void DoSomething(System.Web.HttpRequest request, System.Web.HttpResponse response){

    }

}
```

Structuring your code this way makes it more testable and will save you headaches down the road.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's bad practice?