# call method from other controller that uses Request["name"] variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, request

I am using Asp.net MVC. My HTML code is:

```
<form action="/MobilesController/SaveMobilesAd">
      <input type="text" name="brand" />
      <input type="text" name="color" />
      <!-- other stuff -->
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

There are more than 10 attributes like `brand,color` and I have to input data on 15 different pages. To avoid code redundancy I made a function `MyAd()` implemented all my logic in this function and I just call this function wherever I needed.

```
public class AdController: Controller
    {
         public void MyAd()
         {
              string brand = Request["brand"];
              string color = Request["color"];
              //other stuff. take data from Request variables and save in database.
         }
    }
```

Now to use `MyAd()` in another contoller:

```
public class MobilesController:Controller
{
     AdController ad = new AdContoller();
     public ActionResult SaveMobilesAd()
     {
           //some stuff.
           ad.MyAd();
     }
}
```

Now the problem is when i call `MyAd()` in another controller it gives exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on `Request["brand"]` . How can i avoid this exception or this there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Model` for this?

Comment: Why u are using Request. Just make a class. pass it's object in the Action parameter

Comment: You don't need to bind values manually `string brand = Request["brand"]`. Just define `brand` parameter for this method or model with `brand` property and default binder will do the job. It looks for variables with same names in form values, query string, route data etc

Comment: You're creating a mortal Sin in MVC architecture. You need to use the proper OOP of MVC for this. Use model and if you want bind the object parameters for a little Security. If you want to continue with this, or just you really need this approach for some reason. check out Andrei's Answer.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18347258/5707220

Comment: @orkan thanks a lot. using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request instead of Request solved my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `AdController ad = new AdContoller();` the `Request` object, or rather the instance, does not get shared. The `Request` object inside your `MobilesController` is different than that from the `AdController`. What you could do is the following:

```
public void MyAd(HttpRequestBase externalRequest = null)
{
    HttpRequestBase currentRequest = externalRequest ?? Request;

    string brand = currentRequest ["brand"];
    string color = currentRequest ["color"];
    //...
}
```

You would then call it by passing the `Request` of another Controller instance (if needed, i.e. if not calling from the `AdController`):

```
public class MobilesController: Controller
{
    AdController ad = new AdContoller();
    public ActionResult SaveMobilesAd()
    {
       //some stuff.
       ad.MyAd(Request);
    }
}
```

That being said, I'm not quite comfortable with this approach. It seams to me that you could (should?) refactor this and make a general static method which takes, say, a `Dictionary<string, string>` or even a custom class, and processes the data.

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced `Request` by `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`